# C++ external Function Names Overlapping

Tags: c++, naming

Im currently working on a class in which i have a method called "connect" inside of it Im also calling the winsock function "connect". This of course causes the compiler to give me an error since it doesn't know what to do with it.

*How can I address such a naming Problem in the best way?*

I would like to keep my method name since it describes best whats happening.

I have no control over the name of the winsock function "connect" and even if I had I think it would not make much sense to rename it.

Im pretty sure this or something similar has been answered somewhere else but I was too dumb to find it.

Comment: You can explicitly refer to the socket function as `::connect()`.

Comment: Also use `this->connect()` to use the class function.

Comment: Thanks that already did it. I feel kind of dumb now

Comment: @Simplex What I meant was that you are allowed to post an actual answer to your own question. Having it in the question is helpful, but posting an answer gives better visibility. Someone searching for a solution might skip a question without a posted answer, even if the answer is in the comments or in the question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux got it! makes sense. It looks like someone did it now but i will keep that in mind on future questions.

Comment: "*How can I address such a naming Problem **in the best way**?*" - don't name your class method the same as an existing function in global scope to begin with, then you won't have a conflict.  For instance, use `Connect()` or `connectToServer()` instead of `connect()`.

Comment: @Simplex There's no need to state in your question that it was solved, if you already accepted an answer it's clear so. Also avoid noise and fluff like _"Thanks in advance"_ please.

Comment: @user0042 Well I put that Update there before the other answer was posted but i already got it that its better to create a separate answer. I think a short "Thanks for Help" will not interfere with the clarity of the question and is appropriate. Removing this is very unnecessary in my opinion.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I dont think creating/using multiple functions with the same name but different capitalization will improve Code Quality. I think it will make readability worse than using then using the resolution operator.

Comment: @Simplex _" I think a short "Thanks for Help" will not interfere with the clarity of the question and is appropriate."_ [Nope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While calling `winsock` standard function you can use scope resolution operator `::` before the function name. i.e.

```
::connect(....params....);
```

And when you want to call your class function you can call the class function in following way -

```
this->connect(...params...);
```

Please note that, I have summarized the solutions suggested int the comments so that future user can get help.